# After update to Precise, libc looks hosed and can't update?

Tags: apt, kernel, glibc

Looks like libc is hosed and ldconfig is segfaulting left and right causing issues...

Output when I try to run `apt-get install --reinstall libc6` to reinstall libc(and hopefully ldconfig...):

```
dpkg: error processing fglrx-updates (--confiugre):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing libc-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
libgl1-mesa-glx
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
libqt4-opengl
libqt4-opengl:i386
fglrx-updates
libc-bin
```

Other debug info I figure you want:

```
$ uname -a
Linux linux 3.2.0-25-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 20:30:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04..3 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'd love to get my box up and running again.

**edit**: sent myself further down... I noticed that the name for the architecture for my processor(Intel i7) had changed, from x86_64 to amd64. So I figured, hey, just `apt-get install --reinstall linux` and I'm good, yea?

Now I just have a Grub prompt. I can ls and see my drives. What do I do now :(

Comment: This is weird. I have an Intel i7 processor but when I run `dpkg --print-architecture` I see `amd64`. How the hell?

Answer (score 2):

```
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If this happens with ldconfig, I seriously doubt you can repair it. You can try executing manually ldconfig:

```
sudo ldconfig -vp
```

You can also try to manually download the `libc-bin` package:

```
apt-get download libc-bin
sudo dpkg -i libc-bin*.deb
```

I would remove the `fglrx-updates` package just to be on the safe side too.

```
sudo dpkg --purge fglrx-updates
```